# Distintcount with multiple conflicting filters

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a large table with students test results, and I've been trying to find a way to make a  DISTINCTCOUNT measure from two differents tests, but I've completely failed and have found no help from searching.

Heres an example table:
[Example table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmmFO.png)

The measures that I am using and are working:

```
Number of students = DISTINCTCOUNT('FACT'[StudentID])

    Student below par T10 = CALCULATE([Number of students];'FACT'[TestID]="T10";'FACT'[Result]<4)

    Student below par T11 = CALCULATE([Number of students];'FACT'[TestID]="T11";'FACT'[Result]<12)
```

I am trying to make a DISTINCTCOUNT that counts distinct students from below par T10 AND below par T11. Expected result with the test data set is 2, or 1 for students bb and ff. I tried using CALCULATE with &&, but didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this approach:

```
Below Par Students = SUMX(
 VALUES('FACT'[StudentID]), 
 IF(
  [Student below par T10] > 0
  && [Student below par T11] > 0,
  1
 )
)
```

Comment: Unbelievable, works perfectly! Thank you so much for you help!